# How in PHP to have a MySQL integer increment +1?

Tags: php, mysql

Currently when the user loads a PHP page I have a code that goes into the MySQL Table, and sets an INTeger +1 of itself. The problem is that randomly this number will reset itself to zero! Not sure why this happens.

```
$sql = "UPDATE `MyTable` SET My_INTEGER=My_INTEGER+1";
```

Why does the INTeger reset itself? How can I avoid that, or what is the best practice for updating an INTeger by +1 on a page load?

Comment: you should use a `where` clause if you have more than 1 row. Otherwise, that will update your entire table. Make sure the column is `int` type.

Comment: Do you have any other code which might be causing an issue? For example other queries? If so please show it all.

Comment: We can't answer this without seeing more code. That query in isolation (aside from the `WHERE` clause issue mentioned earlier) will work as expected and will never cause a reset to 0.

Comment: beside of the `where` missing, be sure if the default value of `My_INTEGER` is `0`